# TSLint проверяет pug-шаблоны во Vue-компонентах и выдаёт ошибки

Tags: vue.js, typescript, webpack, tslint

Компонент:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .container

    h1 {{ pageTitle }}
    hr

    div
      div V-Model test:
      div {{ vModelTestProperty }}
      div: input(type='text' v-model='vModelTestProperty')
    hr

    div
      div {{ defaultTextLabel }}
      div: RegularButton(:lettering='Non-default label' :onClickEventHandler='executeTest')
</template>

<script lang="ts">

  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class SPA_Test extends Vue {

    private pageTitle: string = 'SPA test';
    private vModelTestProperty: string = 'What you will input will display here';
    private defaultTextLabel: string = 'Default label';

    public executeTest(): void {
      console.log('test, OK!');
    }
  }
</script>
```

TSLint ругается на этот компонент таким образом:

```
    WARNING in ./SPA_Test.vue ...

    [1, 16]: " should be '
    [18, 14]: " should be '
    [1, 15]: Missing semicolon
    [2, 13]: Missing semicolon
    [4, 7]: Missing semicolon
    [4, 20]: Missing semicolon
    [5, 7]: Missing semicolon
    [7, 8]: Missing semicolon
    [8, 10]: Missing semicolon
    [8, 20]: Missing semicolon
    [9, 10]: Missing semicolon
    [9, 32]: Missing semicolon
    [10, 59]: Missing semicolon
    [11, 7]: Missing semicolon
    [13, 8]: Missing semicolon
    [14, 10]: Missing semicolon
    [14, 30]: Missing semicolon
    [18, 8]: Missing semicolon
    [18, 19]: Missing semicolon
    [33, 10]: Missing semicolon
```

Судя по номерам строк и колонок, TSLint ругается именно на секцию , где никакого TypeScript-а нет и быть не может. Видимо, ts-loader не адаптирован для Vue-компонентов. Я знаю, что есть также [vue-tslint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tslint-loader), а потому нужно раделить эти loader-ы в зависимости от расширения имени файла. Я пытался сделать это таким образом:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      // @see https://regex101.com/r/fqrnCW/1
      test: /^(?:\w|-)*?(?!vue.ts).ts$/,
      loader: 'tslint-loader',
      enforce: 'pre',
      options: {},
    {
      // @see https://regex101.com/r/zY6fLn/1
      test: /^(?:\w|-)*?.vue.ts$/,
      loader: 'vue-tslint-loader',
      enforce: 'pre',
      options: {},
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Немотря на то, что на 101regexp (ссылки даны в комментариях к коду) написанные мной регулярные выражения работают нормально, loader-ы не находят нужные файлы, и теперь TSLint и вовсе молчит, даже если специально не соблюсти его требования.

Comment: Неправильная регулярка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> test: /^(?:\w|-)*?(?!vue.ts).ts$/,
> ```

```
test: /^((?!\.vue\.ts$).)*\.ts$/,
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qIjDhG/2) под данный шаблон попали как `example.vue.ts`, так и `example.ts`.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, исправил.